# OR query with 2 differents fields in firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How can i do a simple query that looks like that in sql but with cloud firestore?
Is there a way without using a composite index ?

`"Select column3 From TableA Where column1 == A OR column2 == A"`

Comment: That's not supported by Firestore.  You'll have to do two queries, one for each field, and merge the results in your app.

Comment: Sad men, that is what i what expecting but i thought there could be a new trick or update to resolve this.  Thanks for your help